# crm status : 0 nodes and 0 resources configured

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, corosync, linux-ha

I've configure corosync and then I got these issue 0 nodes and 0 resources configured.

```
[root@sitampan2 verdana]# crm status
Stack: unknown
Current DC: NONE
Last updated: Thu Jun 16 15:15:40 2016          Last change: Wed Jun 15 14:25:43 2016 by root via cibadmin on sitampan2

0 nodes and 0 resources configured: 160547800 resources DISABLED and 4352 BLOCKED from being started due to failures

Full list of resources:
```

Here is my corosync configuration :

```
compatibility: whitetank
aisexec {
    # Run as root - this is necessary to be able to manage resources with Pacemaker
    user: root
    group: root
}
service {
    # Load the Pacemaker Cluster Resource Manager
    ver: 1
    name: pacemaker
    use_mgmtd: no
    use_logd: no
}
totem {
    version: 2
    #How long before declaring a token lost (ms)
        token: 5000
    # How many token retransmits before forming a new configuration
        token_retransmits_before_loss_const: 10
    # How long to wait for join messages in the membership protocol (ms)
        join: 1000
    # How long to wait for consensus to be achieved before starting a new
    # round of membership configuration (ms)
        consensus: 7500
    # Turn off the virtual synchrony filter
        vsftype: none
    # Number of messages that may be sent by one processor on receipt of the token
        max_messages: 20
    # Stagger sending the node join messages by 1..send_join ms
        send_join: 45
    # Limit generated nodeids to 31-bits (positive signed integers)
        clear_node_high_bit: yes
    # Disable encryption
        secauth: off
    # How many threads to use for encryption/decryption
        threads: 0
    # Optionally assign a fixed node id (integer)
    # nodeid: 1234interface {
    interface {
        ringnumber: 0  
        member {
            memberaddr: 192.168.88.202
        }
        member {
            memberaddr: 192.168.88.201
        }
        bindnetaddr: 192.168.88.0
                mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
                mcastport: 5405
                ttl: 1
        }
}
logging {
    fileline: off
    to_stderr: no
    to_logfile: yes
    to_syslog: yes
    logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
    debug: off
    timestamp: on
    logger_subsys {
        subsys: AMF
        debug: off
    }
}
amf {
    mode: disabled
}
```

I'm using centos 6.7

Here is corosync log file :

```
Jun 15 14:25:22 [1461] sitampan2 corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Node was shut down by a signal
Jun 15 14:25:22 [1461] sitampan2 corosync notice  [SERV  ] Unloading all Corosync service engines.
Jun 15 14:25:22 [1461] sitampan2 corosync info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:22 [1461] sitampan2 corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync configuration map access
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:    error: cfg_connection_destroy: Connection destroyed
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:   notice: pcmk_shutdown_worker:   Shutting down Pacemaker
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:   notice: stop_child:     Stopping pengine: Sent -15 to process 13030
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13030] sitampan2    pengine:   notice: crm_signal_dispatch:    Invoking handler for signal 15: Terminated
Jun 15 14:25:23 [1461] sitampan2 corosync info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13030] sitampan2    pengine:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:    withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [1461] sitampan2 corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync configuration service
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13030] sitampan2    pengine:     info: crm_xml_cleanup:        Cleaning up memory from libxml2
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: pcmk_child_exit:        The pengine process (13030) exited: OK (0)
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:   notice: stop_child:     Stopping attrd: Sent -15 to process 13029
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13029] sitampan2      attrd:   notice: crm_signal_dispatch:    Invoking handler for signal 15: Terminated
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13029] sitampan2      attrd:     info: attrd_shutdown: Shutting down
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13029] sitampan2      attrd:   notice: main:   Cleaning up before exit
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13029] sitampan2      attrd:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:    withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13029] sitampan2      attrd:     info: attrd_cib_destroy_cb:   Connection disconnection complete
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13029] sitampan2      attrd:     info: crm_xml_cleanup:        Cleaning up memory from libxml2
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13026] sitampan2        cib:    error: pcmk_cpg_dispatch:      Connection to the CPG API failed: Library error (2)
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13026] sitampan2        cib:    error: cib_cs_destroy: Corosync connection lost!  Exiting.
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13026] sitampan2        cib:     info: terminate_cib:  cib_cs_destroy: Exiting fast...
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: pcmk_child_exit:        The attrd process (13029) exited: OK (0)
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13026] sitampan2        cib:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:    withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:   notice: stop_child:     Stopping lrmd: Sent -15 to process 13028
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:    error: crm_ipc_read:   Connection to cib_rw failed
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13026] sitampan2        cib:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:    withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:    error: mainloop_gio_callback:  Connection to cib_rw[0x96c2c50] closed (I/O condition=17)
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13028] sitampan2       lrmd:   notice: crm_signal_dispatch:    Invoking handler for signal 15: Terminated
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13026] sitampan2        cib:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:    withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13028] sitampan2       lrmd:     info: lrmd_exit:      Terminating with  0 clients
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13028] sitampan2       lrmd:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:    withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13026] sitampan2        cib:     info: crm_xml_cleanup:        Cleaning up memory from libxml2
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13028] sitampan2       lrmd:     info: crm_xml_cleanup:        Cleaning up memory from libxml2
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:   notice: cib_connection_destroy: Connection to the CIB terminated. Shutting down.
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:     info: stonith_shutdown:       Terminating with  0 clients
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:    withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:     info: main:   Done
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:    withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:     info: main:   Done
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13027] sitampan2 stonith-ng:     info: crm_xml_cleanup:        Cleaning up memory from libxml2
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: pcmk_child_exit:        The lrmd process (13028) exited: OK (0)
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:   notice: stop_child:     Stopping stonith-ng: Sent -15 to process 13027
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:    error: pcmk_cpg_dispatch:      Connection to the CPG API failed: Library error (2)
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:    error: mcp_cpg_destroy:        Connection destroyed
Jun 15 14:25:23 [13024] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: crm_xml_cleanup:        Cleaning up memory from libxml2
Jun 15 14:25:23 [1461] sitampan2 corosync info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [1461] sitampan2 corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync cluster closed process group service v1.01
Jun 15 14:25:23 [1461] sitampan2 corosync info    [QB    ] withdrawing server sockets
Jun 15 14:25:23 [1461] sitampan2 corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync cluster quorum service v0.1
Jun 15 14:25:23 [1461] sitampan2 corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine unloaded: corosync profile loading service
Jun 15 14:25:23 [1461] sitampan2 corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Corosync Cluster Engine exiting normally
```

This is pacemaker log :

```
    Jun 20 11:23:32 [2006] sitampan2       lrmd:   notice: crm_signal_dispatch:     Invoking handler for signal 15: Terminated
Jun 20 11:23:32 [2006] sitampan2       lrmd:     info: lrmd_exit:       Terminating with  0 clients
Jun 20 11:23:32 [2006] sitampan2       lrmd:     info: qb_ipcs_us_withdraw:     withdrawing server sockets
Jun 20 11:23:32 [2006] sitampan2       lrmd:     info: crm_xml_cleanup: Cleaning up memory from libxml2
Jun 20 11:23:42 [8620] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: get_cluster_type:        Detected an active 'corosync' cluster
Jun 20 11:23:42 [8620] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: mcp_read_config: Reading configure for stack: corosync
Jun 20 11:23:42 [8620] sitampan2 pacemakerd:   notice: crm_add_logfile: Switching to /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
Jun 20 11:29:10 [1985] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: crm_log_init:    Changed active directory to /var/lib/pacemaker/cores/root
Jun 20 11:29:10 [1985] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: get_cluster_type:        Detected an active 'corosync' cluster
Jun 20 11:29:10 [1985] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: mcp_read_config: Reading configure for stack: corosync
Jun 20 11:29:10 [1985] sitampan2 pacemakerd:   notice: crm_add_logfile: Switching to /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
Jun 20 11:29:24 [2093] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: get_cluster_type:        Detected an active 'corosync' cluster
Jun 20 11:29:24 [2093] sitampan2 pacemakerd:     info: mcp_read_config: Reading configure for stack: corosync
Jun 20 11:29:24 [2093] sitampan2 pacemakerd:   notice: crm_add_logfile: Switching to /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
```

This is result of cibadmin --query > config.txt in server2 that failed :

```
<cib crm_feature_set="3.0.10" validate-with="pacemaker-2.4" epoch="1" num_updates="0" admin_epoch="0" cib-last-written="Fri Jun 17 15:10:08 2016" update-origin="sitamp$
  <configuration>
    <crm_config>
      <cluster_property_set id="cib-bootstrap-options">
        <nvpair name="no-quorum-policy" value="ignore" id="cib-bootstrap-options-no-quorum-policy"/>
        <nvpair name="stonith-enabled" value="false" id="cib-bootstrap-options-stonith-enabled"/>
        <nvpair name="default-resource-stickiness" value="1000" id="cib-bootstrap-options-default-resource-stickiness"/>
      </cluster_property_set>
    </crm_config>
    <nodes/>
    <resources/>
    <constraints/>
  </configuration>
  <status/>
</cib>
```

And this is result of cibadmin --query > config.txt in server1 that work :

```
<cib crm_feature_set="3.0.10" validate-with="pacemaker-2.4" epoch="4" num_updates="5" admin_epoch="0" cib-last-written="Fri Jun 17 13:16:36 2016" update-origin="sitamp$
  <configuration>
    <crm_config>
      <cluster_property_set id="cib-bootstrap-options">
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-have-watchdog" name="have-watchdog" value="true"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-dc-version" name="dc-version" value="1.1.14-03fa134"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-cluster-infrastructure" name="cluster-infrastructure" value="corosync"/>
      </cluster_property_set>
    </crm_config>
    <nodes>
      <node id="1084774601" uname="sitampan1"/>
    </nodes>
    <resources/>
    <constraints/>
  </configuration>
  <status>
    <node_state id="1084774601" uname="sitampan1" in_ccm="true" crmd="online" crm-debug-origin="do_state_transition" join="member" expected="member">
      <lrm id="1084774601">
        <lrm_resources/>
      </lrm>
      <transient_attributes id="1084774601">
        <instance_attributes id="status-1084774601">
          <nvpair id="status-1084774601-shutdown" name="shutdown" value="0"/>
        </instance_attributes>
      </transient_attributes>
    </node_state>
  </status>
</cib>
```

I've reinstall and server1 and server2 are up but not synchonize. Here the printscreen.

[server1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCebP.png)
[server2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLP7l.png)

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Show the output of `crm_verify -L -V`.

Comment: there's nothing output

Comment: Which version is this? Also: Show the content of the logfile.

Comment: I got from these page https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker
I've edit logfile in my post

Comment: Could you show the config of your cluster, via `cibadmin --query > config.txt`? (This will save the config into the .txt file. Could you please show the content; omit sensitive data if needed?)

Comment: Hi gf, I got new error they said : lrmd:    error: process_lrmd_signon:     Cluster API version must be greater than or equal to 1.1, not 1.0

Comment: Is the same software installed on both nodes?

Comment: I've reinstall pacemaker and server1 and server2 are up. But they're not synchron. I'he update my post. Thank you

Comment: As the screenshots show, you're using two different software versions (have a look at the line reading `Current DC: ...`. I'm off regarding your problem / topic, SF doesn't work for "debugging sessions" like this. Besides, it seems that you're not really "helping yourself", but just stating the current status quo. All the best and good luck!

Comment: after working for a long time, finally it's work. It's all about multicast. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you only have two nodes, you'd want to add this:

```
quorum {
  provider: corosync_votequorum
  expected_votes: 2
}
```

Comment: In server1 it's work, but in server2 didn't work. I don't know why

Comment: I've reinstall and server1 and server2 are up but not synchonize. Here the printscreen. I've update my post

Comment: @Adi: Looks like a firewall/networking problem to me. Do you have iptables started? If so, do you have rules for udp port 5405 and 5404 between the nodes?

Comment: after working for a long time, finally it's work. It's all about multicast. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

in totem section, you can try to add this line:

```
rrp_mode: none
```

If it still has error, try to add more this section:

```
quorum {
        provider: corosync_votequorum
        expected_votes: 3
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. any other solution?